# Enable WMS GetFeatureInfo request in Leaflet using R?

Tags: r, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I've been using R with Leaflet and Shiny to produce a web map that is accessible to the public online. It is a real-time air temperature map of Tasmania, Australia based on current Bureau or meteorology weather station observations. You can view a prototype here: http://144.6.226.103/shiny/

Each air temperature map is referenced from GeoServer via WMS. I have produced the R code below for reference.

I'm trying to enable the GETFeatureInfo function so users are able to query each map spatially by clicking on any location thereby producing a popup and showing a temperature value.

I'm wondering if this is possible to set up in R?

```
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet.extras)
    m<-leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(147, -42, zoom = 8) %>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090511AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090511AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090510AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090510AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090509AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090509AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090508AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090508AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090507AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090507AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSTiles(
              "http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090506AEST"),
              group = paste0("TempPrediction_2019090506AEST"),
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE, version ="1.3.0",opacity = 0.5))%>%
            addWMSLegend(uri=paste0('http://144.6.226.103:8080/geoserver/TempPred/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=TempPrediction_2019090511AEST'))%>%
            addLayersControl(
              baseGroups = c(paste0("TempPrediction_2019090511AEST (°C)"),paste0("TempPrediction_2019090510AEST (°C)"),paste0("TempPrediction_2019090509AEST (°C)"),paste0("TempPrediction_2019090508AEST (°C)"),paste0("TempPrediction_2019090507AEST (°C)"),paste0("TempPrediction_2019090506AEST (°C)")),
              position = 'bottomleft',
              options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

Comment: trevi solution is not working for me. If I use `addWMS()` the WMS-layer is not visible. If I use `addWMSTiles()` I don't get the getFeatureInfo Informations. Has anyone implemeted it correctly? My code, copied from trevis post:
```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)
library(XML) ui <- fluidPage( # Application title titlePanel("Test"), mainPanel( leafletOutput("mymap") ) ) server <- function(input, output) { output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>% addTiles(group = "base") %>% addWMS(baseUrl = "http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service", layers = c("TOPO-WMS","OSM-Overlay-W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible to get the `GetFeatureInfo` feature out-of-the-box with the `leaflet.extras2` package by calling the `leaflet.extras2::addWMS()` function.

See here below an example from the package developer:

```
#remotes::install_github('trafficonese/leaflet.extras2')

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)
library(XML)


leaflet()  %>%
  addTiles(group = "base") %>%
  addWMS(baseUrl = "http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service",
         layers = c("TOPO-WMS","OSM-Overlay-WMS"),
         # layers = c("OSM-Overlay-WMS"),
         group = "wmsgroup",
         options = leaflet::WMSTileOptions(
           transparent = TRUE,
           format = "image/png",
           info_format = "text/html",
           tiled = FALSE
         )) %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = "base",
                   # overlayGroups = c("wmsgroup"))
                   overlayGroups = c("TOPO-WMS","OSM-Overlay-WMS"))
```

[image: output leaflet map]

Comment: Thank you - very neat! Another alternative I discovered was to use the ObserveEvent function in Shiny in conjunction with implementing an extract query when users click on a location within the webmap. The 'click' produces a set of coordinates which can be used to extract data at a location on-the-fly.

Comment: Hi @MatW, I was wondering if you could share a working snippet of your implementation. Seems like a clean way, without extra dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible (yet). GetFeatureInfo requests have not been integrated in `r` `leaflet`. This was an issue in the `leaflet.extras` package, but not (yet) implemented. See https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/issues/84