# Using WMS getFeatureInfo() in shiny and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, shiny

I like to get the getFeatureInfo by a click like it is mentioned [in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334004/enable-wms-getfeatureinfo-request-in-leaflet-using-r) so that the information is shown in a popup window.
I tried trevis solution but it is not working for me. If I use `addWMS()` the WMS-layer is not visible and there is no info. If I use `addWMSTiles()` I don't get the getFeatureInfo Informations. Has anyone implemeted it correctly?

My code, after [trevis post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334004/enable-wms-getfeatureinfo-request-in-leaflet-using-r):

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)
library(XML)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Test"),
   


      mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("mymap")
      )
   )



server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({leaflet()  %>%
    addTiles(group = "base") %>%
    addWMS(baseUrl = "http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service",
           layers = c("TOPO-WMS","OSM-Overlay-WMS"),
           # layers = c("OSM-Overlay-WMS"),
           group = "wmsgroup",
           options = leaflet::WMSTileOptions(
             transparent = TRUE,
             format = "image/png",
             info_format = "text/html",
             tiled = FALSE
           )) %>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = "base",
                     # overlayGroups = c("wmsgroup"))
                     overlayGroups = c("TOPO-WMS","OSM-Overlay-WMS"))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What actual WMS GetMap and GetFeatureInfo requests are sent?

Comment: I found the problem. It works in the browser but not in the R-Studio Preview and I forgot to try it there.